# How to deploy two projects (Razor and Api) in Asp core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, deployment

originally I make a web application (Razor Page Application) with Asp core 3.1 and it's work and been published to my host.

The client wants a mobile app, so I decide to build API. I know I can create the API in the same project or create new separate project (solution) for this purpose, but what is the best practice?

I saw a lot of developers make more than one project in solution (Model Project, Repository Project and the main project),
so I create a new API project

[image: new API project added to my solution]

But now I don't know how to deploy and publish my second project
I tried to publish it and then put it in separate sub-domain, but I get error: HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process) // it not seem to be web config problem

My question is about best practice. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Khorshid, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to host your ASP.NET Core API app as an IIS sub-application (sub-app) on same site that you used to host your Razor Page app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sub-applications

And please note that we need to create and specify a ***separate*** app pool to the sub-app when using the in-process hosting model, otherwise the site would not work well.

Comment: Thanks, It's work in this way, Put the API project in  IIS sub-application (or sub-domains) and it will work.

Comment: Hi @Khorshid, if the reply did help resolve the issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)